# Has Shadowrun 4 been implemented as a MUD or similiar?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, online-roleplaying

There's a few MUDs and MUSHES for the older rulesets out there, has this ever been done with 4th edition?
The one findable via the usual Mudlistings is in very early beta and not playable.

Comment: Discussion of whether this is on-topic on meta: [Are MUDs/MUSHes/etc. that use RPG systems on-topic?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/are-muds-mushes-etc-that-use-rpg-systems-on-topic)